# Why won't my Windows PE RAM Disk (CD-ROM) boot?

Tags: boot, windows-pe

I created a Windows PE RAM disk (CD-ROM) from the [instructions on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx). I'm on a Windows 7 x64 system and my "reference" system is the same. I changed the boot priority to CD-ROM first on the reference system, but it comes up with an error message like

> The boot device is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions in step 2 leaves out one important step. You must copy a `boot.wim` into the `sources` directory. The command would be something like

```
cmd> copy c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim c:\winpe_x86\iso\sources\boot.wim
```

I've taken the liberty of scripting the entire process (for ISOs on x86 and x64 architectures with imagex support). You can pick up the scripts on my [github repo](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/nugetpackages/tree/winperamdisk) or as a [chocolatey package](http://chocolatey.org/packages/winperamdisk).

(Shamelessly copied from a comment at the bottom of the [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx).)